# Firebase observeEventType:FEventTypeValue Stopped Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

The below code used to work just fine, up until this morning. Now, the callback fires when initializing once, as expected, but never fires again. Changing the data at the root ref does NOT cause the callback to fire anymore. I should note that listening for other event types besides FEventTypeValue still seems to work.

Is anyone else experiencing this? I have tried enabling Firebase Logging, but nothing shows up there either.

```
self.myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://some-url.firebaseio.com/matches/%@", self.match.matchID]];

[self.myRootRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    NSLog(@"Firebase observer callback...");

}];
```

Edit:

Modifying myRootRef fixed it. I changed it from strong to retain. Can someone please explain why this worked with strong up until now and suddenly stopped working?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Firebase *myRootRef;
```

Changed to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Firebase *myRootRef;
```

Another edit:

This is all a lie. Firebase must have fixed an intermittent issue on their end. Changing it back to strong works as expected again. The issue isn't happening anymore.